# Как правильно указать парсеру класс

Tags: python, парсер

Пишу уже который день парсер для сайта [https://prozorro.gov.ua/tender/search?query=освіта&value=10000](https://prozorro.gov.ua/tender/search?query=%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%82%D0%B0&value=10000) [image: Скриншот сайта]

Мне надо получить:'вебсайт','местонахождение','Контакты' и т.д. Но class у них у всех один. Как сделать так что бы выводились разные данные?

```
'title' : item.find('div', class_='tender--head--title col-sm-9').get_text(),
'mail' : item.find('a', class_='word-break').get_text(),

'naimeniv' : item.find_all('td', class_='col-sm-6'),
'city' : item.find('td', class_='col-sm-6').get_text(),
```

Comment: Судя по структуре - это хранится в таблице, можете найти эту таблицу и итерироваться по её тегам *<tr>* доставая классы *col-sm-#*

Comment: Да, всё храниться в таблице, но мне нужны отдельные данные, например 'Найменування:' = 'Своему значению '

Comment: А там всё в классе col-sm-6

Comment: Название хранится в *col-sm-4*, а значение в *col-sm-6*. У вас на скрне даже так показано

Comment: Ну а может же быть такое что я захочу вывести значение наименований, а мне выдаст код

Comment: смотрите первый комментарий

Comment: После написания ответа, вспомнил, что большое количество проблем с парсингом решается через нахождение API для ресурса. Посмотрите это https://data.gov.ua/en/dataset/f9c0acdb-23c5-4a2d-b549-9868df8ca927/resource/dd45ed7a-ecc7-4839-8513-85c3332c9310. Вероятно может быть полезным для Вас

Answer (score 0):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup
import requests
import re

ua = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2227.0 Safari/537.36'

# Представим что мы уже получили ссылку на страницу компании
url = 'https://prozorro.gov.ua/tender/UA-2020-08-12-001159-a'

response = requests.get(
    url,
    headers={
        'User-Agent': ua
    }
)
soup = Soup(response.content, 'html.parser')

customer_tab = soup.find('table', class_='tender--customer')

params = {
    row.find('td', class_='col-sm-4').text.strip(): row.find('td', class_='col-sm-6').text.strip() for row in
    customer_tab.find_all('tr')
}

title = params.get('Найменування:')
person, phone, email, *_ = re.split(r'\s*?\n\s*', params.get('Контактна особа:', '---\n---\n---'))
address = re.sub(r'\s*?\n\s*', '', params.get('Місцезнаходження:', '----'))
site = params.get('Вебсайт:', '----')

print(person, phone, email, site, address, sep='\n')
# ДВНЗ "Національна академія внутрішніх справ"
# Леся Барановська
# +380966881605
# baranovskalesja@ukr.net
# http://www.naiau.kiev.ua
# 03035, Україна, м. Київ обл., м. Київ,  пл. Солом'янська, 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант можно использовать такой подход - вытащить все значения классов `col-sm-4` и   `col-sm-6` и скрестить их (см. код):

```
names = [name.text.strip() for name in bs.find_all('td', class_='col-sm-4')]
vals = [val.text.strip() for val in bs.find_all('td', class_='col-sm-6')]

result = dict(zip(names, vals))

# Результат - {'Найменування:': 'відділ освіти Літинської райдержадміністрації', 'Код ЄДРПОУ:': '02141383', ...}
```

Дальше доставать все необходимые значения